# How to update threejs morph targets from blender GLTF shape keys

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I have a blender file with several shape keys. When I drag the slider in blender between 0 and 1, I can manipulate the shape key.

(screenshot):
https://share.getcloudapp.com/bLuw8L0W

I am exporting the GLTF and importing it in threejs.

If I `console.log` the mesh from the GLTF, I can see the shape keys from blender in the `morphTargetDictionary`, and I have set up a GUI to update the `morphTargetInfluences` for each shape key:

https://share.getcloudapp.com/6quP71l7

```
folder
.add(params, "influence2", 0, 1)
.step(0.01)
.onChange(function (value) {
  console.log(dodec.morphTargetInfluences[1]);
  dodec.morphTargetInfluences[1] = value;
  //dodec.updateMorphTargets();
});
```

but updating these morphTargetInfluences seems to have no affect. How do I set this up so that I can achieve the same effect within Three.js that I can have within blender by moving the sliders for each shape key?

**update**

Here is a codepen of what I have currently:

https://codepen.io/heaversm/pen/xxVNmdb

Comment: Any chances to share a live example with your code? It seems you are essentially doing the same like the following official morph target demo (https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets).

Comment: Your second `getcloudapp` link is giving me an error: "Oops. There's nothing here."

Comment: @Marquizzo - updated.

Comment: @Mugen87 - here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/heaversm/pen/xxVNmdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you want to target is the mesh, which is `dodec = scene.getObjectByName("Solid_0");`. Inspecting what `dodec` is until you find a mesh will lead you here.

GLTF exports nested groups, so your mesh may be in a group in general.

You also need to set morphTargets: true on your material:

```
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0xffa400,
  emissive: 0xbb5a5a,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  flatShading: true,
  morphTargets: true, // you need this
});
```